# How to assign from one list to another?

Tags: python, list

If I get 3 lists

```
List1 = ["A","B","C"] 
List2 = [1,2,3]
List3 = [4,5,6]
```

How can I assign and sum List2 & List3  to List1 so that

```
A = 5
B = 7
c = 9
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. What if I had List2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]? How can I do it now?

Comment: Try it yourself first. It's just an extra loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {key: a + b for key, a, b in zip(List1, List2, List3)}
{'A': 5, 'C': 9, 'B': 7}
```

I must admit your question was confusing. Maybe you are looking for this instead?

```
>>> List1 = [a + b for a, b in zip(List2, List3)]
>>> List1
[5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `zip` `List2` and `List3` to get

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

you can then sum individual tuples with `sum` function like this

```
List1 = map(sum, zip(List2, List3))
print List1
# [5, 7, 9]
```

If you are looking for a way to create a dictionary out of it, you can simply `zip` the `List1` and the `sum` values which we calculated with `map` and `sum` to get

```
zip(List1, map(sum, zip(List2, List3)))
# [('A', 5), ('B', 7), ('C', 9)]
```

And if we pass that to the `dict` function, we get a new dictionary :)

```
dict(zip(List1, map(sum, zip(List2, List3))))
# {'A': 5, 'C': 9, 'B': 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     >>> total=[]
     >>> List1 = ["A","B","C"]
     >>> List2 = [1,2,3]
     >>> List3 = [4,5,6]
     >>> for i in range(len(List2)):
         total.append(List2[i]+List3[i])
     >>> total
         #[5, 7, 9]
     >>>dic={}
     >>> for i in range(len(List1)):
             dic.update({List1[i]:total[i]})
     >>> dic
        #{'A': 5,'C': 9,'B': 7}
```