# How to combine lists? (Python)

Tags: python, list

If I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = ["X","Y","Z"]
list2 = [1,2,3]
```

How can I combine them to make a another list:

```
list3 = [[1,"X"],[2,"Y"],[3,"Z"]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I explained this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23114803/1903116) to your previous question.

Comment: @thefourtheye, Yeah, I thought this looked familiar

Comment: I Apologize, if this is a duplicate question. I'm new to python so couldn't really link and undertand the relationship between this and my previous question. Especially with the sum and dictionary parts of some answers. Sorry again.

Comment: @DejaVu Nevertheless, I have answered to show how you could use it specifically in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `zip` to get tuples of values at corresponding indices in the two lists, and then cast each `tuple` to a `list`. So:

```
[list(t) for t in zip(list1, list2)]
```

is all you need to do.

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list3 = [list(t) for t in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> list3
[[1, 'X'], [2, 'Y'], [3, 'Z']]
```